# Interview type questions

Tags: java, .net, sql

I have an interview coming up, and I was just wondering the easiest way to explain the following questions:

What is object oriented programming?
What is the difference between an abstract and interface class?
Describe an application lifecycle:

I know the "book" definitions, but not like a short interview type answer.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not a careers advice site.

Comment: You might want to see if http://programmers.stackexchange.com is better suited to your questions.

Comment: I had actually found the answers I was looking for on this website, but wanted a little more insight on them, that's why I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OOP**

In order to clearly understand the object orientation, take your “hand” as an example.

The “hand” is a class. Your body has two objects of type hand, named left hand and right hand. Their main functions are controlled/managed by a set of electrical signals sent through your shoulders (through an interface).

So the shoulder is an interface which your body uses to interact with your hands. The hand is a well architected class. The hand is being re-used to create the left hand and the right hand by slightly changing the properties of it.

**Interface class**

An interface is a contract: the guy writing the interface say "hey, I accept things looking that way", and the guy using the interface says "OK, the class I write looks that way".

An interface is an empty shell, there are only the signatures (name / params / return type) of the methods. The methods do not contain anything. The interface can't do anything. It's just a pattern.

**Abstract class**

Abstract classes, unlike interfaces, are classes. There are more expensive to use because there is a lookup to do when you inherit from them.

Abstract classes look a lot like interfaces, but they have something more : you can define a behavior for them. It's more about a guy saying "these classes should look like that, and they got that in common, so fill in the blanks!".